# Is Universal Control flaky for you between Intel Mac and M1 mac?

Tags: universal-control

Computer A: intel imac, 2020, monterery 12.4

Computer B: m1, macbook pro, 2020, monterey 12.4

Computer C: ipad pro, 2017

I have universal control set up between these 3 machines. The Universal Control connection works fine for a bit between the Computer A and B but then suddenly stops working. Might happen after only 10 min, but more often it takes a couple of hours before the problem occurs.

Connection between A and C is usually never lost.

To restore the connection, I turn UC off and back on.

Anyone else experiencing this? Anyone know of anything I can try to fix this annoyance?

Comment: I don't think it's wifi because the ipad and mbp are right next to each other. I'll lose one but not the other. Plus, the two computers are networked together. I had the same problem with and without the computers being networked.

Comment: Holy crap. Just happened after I finished typing this. I wonder if some 3rd party software might be the cause.

Comment: It's *extremely* flaky, I created a separate issue relating to sleep here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/444265/universal-control-stops-working-after-putting-ipad-to-sleep-12-5

It doesn't seem to be anything third party as I reproduced this after factory resetting the Mac and iPad.

Comment: I got it working once, can't get it working again, Apple phone support knows nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I have similar experiences but with a much lesser frequency of occurrence.

In my opinion it has to be with the stability of the software implementation rather than the wireless interference (I ruled that one out).

I believe it will get better with future releases of macOS and iPadOS.

Comment: I think so as well. After I reboot the machines, it happens less frequently. But after a while, it starts to become really frequent.

Comment: It seems they made it even worse in the recent update. Is this working better or worse for you on 12.5?

Comment: @Hackeron Better.

Answer (score 0):

If I turn off the "Cursor and Keyboard" setting on the iPad in the "Handoff" settings in "General", the problem no longer occurs.

This doesn't solve the problem, of course, as I still want to use my iPad, too.

Comment: I have the same problem! - On the phone to apple 15+ hours now and 10+ calls, no solution yet. I recorded a video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZ4VbEe8nHM - did you ever get it working?

Comment: @Hackeron I just came back off of vacation and upgraded all my devices to latest macOS/iOS versions. So far, so good since yesterday.

Comment: That's good to hear, I hope Apple help resolve this for me tomorrow as no matter what I do, it just won't work for me :(

Answer (score -1):

No flakeyness - So far so good for me.

What’s your wireless environment look like? Lots of Bluetooth and 2.4 GHz network interference? Lots of USB-C cables that might be wearing out or not be well shielded?

Comment: Seems unrelated to wifi, in my case I tried switching off all devices leaving just a MacBook and an iPad and it's extremely flaky. I recorded a video too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3fNYcsd_2h0 -- have you not had any issues at all? what devices are you using and what wifi environment?